# 'of' vs 'from' operator

Tags: rxjs

Is the only difference between `Observable.of` and `Observable.from` the arguments format? Like the `Function.prototype.call` and `Function.prototype.apply`?

```
Observable.of(1,2,3).subscribe(() => {})
Observable.from([1,2,3]).subscribe(() => {})
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Not quite. When passing an array to `Observable.from`, the only difference between it and `Observable.of` is the way the arguments are passed.

However, `Observable.from` will accept an [argument](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from) that is

> a subscribable object, a Promise, an Observable-like, an Array, an iterable or an array-like object to be converted

There is no similar behaviour for `Observable.of` - which always accepts only values and performs no conversion.

Answer (score 283):

It is important to note the difference between `of` and `from` when passing an array-like structure (including strings):

```
Observable.of([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

would print the whole array at once.

On the other hand,

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

prints the elements 1 by 1.

For strings the behaviour is the same, but at character level.

Comment: What if 
Observable.of(1, 2, 3).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

Comment: @xiaoke Then surely it is 3 separate emissions (1, then 2, then 3).

Comment: @xiaoke 1, 2, 3 is a stream of data emitted one after the other(as these values are not wrapped inside a data structure) so the behaviour of such a stream would be same in case of 'of' or 'from'. However an array is single stream of data when passed to 'of' and one by one stream of data when passed to 'from' as mentioned in the answer as well.

Answer (score 60):

**One line Difference :**

```
       let fruits = ['orange','apple','banana']
```

**from** : Emit the items one by one of array. For example

```
    from(fruits).subscribe(console.log) // 'orange','apple','banana'
```

**of** : Emit the whole array at once. For example

```
 of(fruits).subscribe(console.log) //  ['orange','apple','banana']
```

**NOTE:** **of**  operator can behave as **from** operator  with **spread operator**

```
 of(...fruits).subscribe(console.log) //  'orange','apple','banana'
```

Comment: Practically this is the accurate answer, don't know why not many people noticed the difference.

Comment: Simply the best answer! As concised as it should be.

Answer (score 25):

***of*** will emit all values at once

***from*** will emit all values one by one

***of*** with ***spread*** operator = ***from*** operator

[image]

Answer (score 24):

Another interesting fact is Observable.of([]) will be an empty array when you subscribe to it. 
Where as when you subscribe to  Observable.from([])  you wont get any value.

This is important when you do a consecutive operation with switchmap.

Ex:
In the below example, I am saving a job and then sites, and then comments as a stream.

```
.do((data) => {
            this.jobService.save$.next(this.job.id);
        })
        .switchMap(() => this.jobService.addSites(this.job.id, this.sites)
            .flatMap((data) => {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    // get observables for saving
                    return Observable.forkJoin(jobSiteObservables);
                } else {
                    **return Observable.of([]);**
                }
            })).do((result) => {
            // ..
        })
        .switchMap(() => this.saveComments())
....
```

if there's no site to save, ie; data.length = 0 in addSite section, the above code is returning Observable.of([]) and then goes to save comments. But if you replace it with Observable.from([]), the succeeding methods will not get called.

[rxfiddle](https://rxfiddle.net/#type=editor&code=bGV0IGEgPSBSeC5PYnNlcnZhYmxlLmZyb20oW10pCgoKYS5zdWJzY3JpYmUoYiA9PiBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyhiKSkKCgpsZXQgYyA9IFJ4Lk9ic2VydmFibGUub2YoW10pCgoKYy5zdWJzY3JpYmUoZCA9PiBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyhkKSk=)

Comment: This is due to function signature difference: The equivalent of `Observable.from([])` would be `Observable.of()` – without an empty array inside! If you provide an empty array inside `…of()`, then you do provide a value (1 value, an empty array that is). The `from`-equivalent of that would be `Observable.from([ [] ])` (an array with one empty array)

Answer (score 9):

`from`: Create observable from array, promise or iterable. Takes only one value. For arrays, iterables and strings, all contained values will be emitted as a sequence

```js
const values = [1, 2, 3];
from(values); // 1 ... 2 ... 3
```

`of`: Create observable with variable amounts of values, emit values in sequence, but arrays as single value

```js
const values = [1, 2, 3];
of(values, 'hi', 4, 5); // [1, 2, 3] ... 'hi' ... 4 ... 5
```

Answer (score 5):

1. from returns notification in chunks i.e. one by one.
   for eg: from("abcde") will return a => b => c => d => e
2. of returns complete notification.
   for eg: of("abcde") will return abcde.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sckwsw?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Answer (score 2):

The `from` operator takes source of events. `from(source)`

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5]
from(array); //where array is source of events, array[of events]


let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // executor (the producing code, "singer")
});
from(promise); //where promise is source of event, promise(of event)





let observable = Observable.create(function(observer) {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
  observer.next(3);
  observer.next(4);
  observer.next(5);
  observer.complete();
});
from(observable); // where obsservable is source of events.
```

The `of` operator takes intividual events. `of(event1, event2, event3)`

```
of(1,2,3,4,5); // where 1,2,3,4,5 are individual events
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to remember the difference when the analogy with .call / .apply methods came into my mind.

You can think of it this way:

- normally, all arguments, that are passed separately (separated by comma), are also emitted separately, in the order they were passed. `of()` just emits all arguments one by one as they are (like `.call` method passes arguments to the function it was called on)
- `from()` is like `.apply` in a sense that it can take an array of values as an argument, and convert array elements into separate arguments, separated by comma.

So, if you have an array and want each element to be emitted separately, you can use `from()` or get the same behavior by using `of()` with spread operator, like `of(...arr)`.

It's bit more complicated then that (`from` can also take observables) but with this analogy it will probably be easier to remember the main difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true that `of` will result in an output in single go and `from` will happen one at a time. But there is more difference related to number of arguments and type of arguments.

You can pass any number of arguments to the `Of`. Each argument emitted separately and one after the other. It sends the Complete signal in the end.

However you can send only one argument to the `from` operator and that one argument should be a type of

- an Array,
- anything that behaves like an array
- Promise
- any iterable object
- collections
- any observable like object

For example you can send a raw object like

```
myObj={name:'Jack',marks:100}
```

to `of` operator to convert to Observable.

```
obj$:Observable<any> = of(myObj);
```

but you can not send this raw object `myObj` to `from` operator simply because it is not iterable or array like collection.

for more detail : [visit here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/rxjs-observable-using-create-of-from-in-angular/)

Answer (score -1):

from operator may accept one of

promises
iterable
arrays
observable

from emits each individual item from the observable , can also do conversions.

of operator takes in the raw value and emits the value from the observable.

```
import {from, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

const ofObs = of([1,2,3]);
const fromObs = from([2,3,4]);

const basicObs = Observable.create(observer=>{
    observer.next(100);
    observer.next(200);
    observer.next(300);
})
const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    resolve(100);
})

const array = [1,2,3];
const iterbale  = "Dhana";

// const myObs = from(ofObs);//possible and can emit individual item value everytime 1, then ,2 , then 3
// const myObs = from(fromObs);//possbile and can emit individual item value everytime 1, then ,2 , then 3
// const myObs = from(basicObs);//possbile and can emit individual item value everytime 100, then ,200 , then 300
const myObs = from(promise);//possible can emit value 100
// const myObs = array(promise);//possible and can emit individual item value everytime 1, then ,2 , then 3
// const myObs = iterable(promise);//possible and can emit individual item value everytime D then h then a then n then a


myObs.subscribe(d=>console.log(d))
```

```
import {from, of} from 'rxjs';

const basicOf1 = of([1,2,3,4,5,6]) // emits entire array of events
const basicfrom1 = from([1,2,3,4,5,6]) //emits each event at a time

const basicOf2 = of(1,2,3,4,5,6) // emits each event at a time
// const basicfrom2 = from(1,2,3,4,5,6) //throws error
//Uncaught TypeError: number is not observable

const basicOf3 = of(...[1,2,3,4,5,6]) // emits each event at a time
const basicfrom3 = from(...[1,2,3,4,5,6]) //throws error
//Uncaught TypeError: number is not observable
basicOf3.subscribe(d=>console.log(d))
```

[Here is the link to codepen](https://codepen.io/dhanatontanahal/pen/OJbOweL)