# async pipe does not work on rxjs from observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-pipe, angular-observable

I want to use async pipe on a simple observable returned by from:

in component.ts

```
 myData$ = from([
    { name: "Los Angeles", population: "3.9 million" },
    { name: "New York", population: "8,4 million" },
    { name: "Chicago", population: "2.7 million" },
  ]);
```

in component.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let city of myData$ | async">
      {{city}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Error that I get:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Chicago'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Please use `of` operator instead of `from` operator in RxJs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['of' vs 'from' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704552/of-vs-from-operator)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `from` operator, you will be receiving each array items one by one, instead of the entire array. So change the `from` operator to `of` so you will be receiving the entire array and loop over it.

```
myData$ = of([
    { name: "Los Angeles", population: "3.9 million" },
    { name: "New York", population: "8,4 million" },
    { name: "Chicago", population: "2.7 million" },
  ]);

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let city of myData$ | async">
    {{ city | json }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the type of `myData$`. It will be `Observable<{ name:string, population }>`, however ngFor won't work that way, it needs array, thus you should pass type of `Observable<{ name:string, population }[]>` to async pipe and ngFor will work.

That's why you need to use `of()` instead of `from()`